# sort df based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as shown below

df:

```
product_x  year     total_price      total_sale
A          2016     50               200           
B          2016     200              100           
A          2017     250              250           
B          2017     1000             300           
A          2018     100              50           
B          2018     900              600
K          2016     20               300
D          2016     100              450
```

I would like to sort df as shown below.

```
product_x  year_c   total_price      total_sale
D          2016     100              450
A          2016     50               200           
B          2016     200              100
K          2016     20               300
B          2017     1000             300 
A          2017     250              250
B          2018     900              600
A          2018     100              50
```

first preference is increasing order of year_c and then decreasing order of toatal_sale.

I tried below code.

```
df = df.sort_values(['year_c', 
                    'total_sale'], ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine. If you want sort order to be different by columns, you can pass a list to `ascending=`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['year_c', 
                'total_sale'], ascending=[True,False])
```

See docs for more details: [pd.DataFrame.sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 1):

Define the sort order separately for each column:

```
df.sort_values(['year_c', 'total_sale'], ascending=[True, False])
```

(ascending by *year_c*, descending by *total_sale*).