# Printing values for the corresponding variable in descending order

Tags: python

Say we take two inputs, a dictionary and a list of variables.

```
dict1 = {'One': [300, 600],'Two': [9300, 1300]}
variables = ['x', 'y']
```

We want to print in descending order like below:

```
x :
9300 Two
300 One

y :
1300 Two
600 One
```

To help you understand, the first value in the list corresponds to x, the second corresponds to y and so on...

How do we tackle this? I've tried creating a list of tuples and then reverse sorting but had no success.

Comment: With what key do you want to sort? Will it always be the first element in the value list?

Comment: *"I've tried creating a list of tuples and then reverse sorting but had no success"* - This seems like a fine solution.  What problems did you encounter?  It would help if you edited your question to include code for your attempts and any associated error messages.

Comment: I'll try add my attempt when i'm home. @SeyiDaniel sorry if I misunderstood what you're asking, but we want to sort the first values (300,9300) which correspond to x, then we want to sort (600,1300) in descending order which corresponds to y.

Comment: IIUC, do you want to **sort the rows by x (increasing) then y (decreasing)**?

Comment: @SeyiDaniel please have a look at the comment I gave to your solution, i think it needs a small change and is almost there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you find this helpful?

```
dict1 =  {'One': [8400, 6000, 1800, 650],'Two': [300, 500, 1390, 9300]}
variables = ['x','y','z','a']

dict1_tuple = list(dict1.items()) #extract dictionary key-value pairs to list of tuples
sorted_tuple = sorted(dict1_tuple, key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True) #sort tuples list using the first element in value in reversed order
#print items using nested FOR loop in shown format
for i in variables:
    print(i, ':')
    j = variables.index(i)
    for a in range(len(sorted_tuple)):
        print(sorted_tuple[a][1][j], sorted_tuple[a][0])
```

> Output

```
x :
8400 One
300 Two
y :
6000 One
500 Two
z :
1800 One
1390 Two
a :
650 One
9300 Two
```

> ### EDIT

```
dict1 =  {'One': [8400, 6000, 1800, 650],'Two': [300, 500, 1390, 9300]}
variables = ['x','y','z','a']

dict1_tuple = list(dict1.items())
sorted_tuple = sorted(dict1_tuple, key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True)

for i in variables:
    print(i,':')
    j = variables.index(i)
    output = []
    for a in range(len(sorted_tuple)):
        output.append((sorted_tuple[a][1][j], sorted_tuple[a][0]))
    output = sorted(output, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
    for b in range(len(sorted_tuple)):
        print(output[b][0], output[b][1])
```

Comment: Hi this is almost it. But for variable a it should print "9300 Two" followed bt "650 One" instead as the goal is to print in descending order. How would you modify your code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you mean the following (using pandas package, and creating a dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[300, 600], 'y':[9300, 1300]}, index=['One','Two'])
df  
       x     y
One  300  9300
Two  600  1300
```

Then I think you want to [**sort the dafaframe by x (increasing) then y (decreasing)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614419/sort-df-based-on-multiple-conditions), see [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
>>> df.sort_values(['x','y'], ascending=[True, False])
       x     y
One  300  9300
Two  600  1300
```

i.e. not **sort each column individually**:

```
>>> df.apply(sorted, axis=0)
       x     y
One  300  1300
Two  600  9300
```

and not **sort the rows of the dataframe by 'x' then 'y' increasing** (`df.sort_values(['x','y'])`)

Answer (score 0):

The first task is to transform the inputs `dict1 = {'One': [300, 600],'Two': [9300, 1300]}` and `variables = ['x', 'y']` into a "master dictionary" `{'x': {300: 'One', 9300: 'Two'}, 'y': {600: 'One', 1300: 'Two'}}`.
This can be done with some dict comprehension:

```py
master_dict = {var: {coor[i]: name for name, coor in dict1.items()} for i, var in enumerate(variables)}
```

The second task is to sort. For every dictionary `dict`, we can sort it by key using `sorted(dict.items())`, so in our dict comprehension:

```py
master_dict = {var: sorted({coor[i]: name for name, coor in dict1.items()}.items(), reverse=True) for i, var in enumerate(variables)}
master_dict = {var: sorted([(coor[i], name) for name, coor in dict1.items()], reverse=True) for i, var in enumerate(variables)}
# we can turn the inner dict comprehension into a list comprehension with key-value tuples and remove the `.items()`
assert master_dict == {'x': [(9300, 'Two'), (300, 'One')], 'y': [(1300, 'Two'), (600, 'One')]}
```

The only thing left is to print according to the `master_dict`:

```py
for var, kvps in master_dict.items():
    print(f'{var}:')
    for coor, name in kvps:
        print(coor, name)
    print()
```

---

**Output for `dict1={'One': [8400, 6000, 1800, 650],'Two': [300, 500, 1390, 9300]}, variables=['x', 'y', 'z', 'a']`:**

```
x:
8400 One
300 Two

y:
6000 One
500 Two

z:
1800 One
1390 Two

a:
9300 Two
650 One
```